# Avoiding selection symbology when export map in ArcGIS Desktop 10.6

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, export, select

I have to export the layout of my map to jpg while iterating and zooming to selected features by means of a Python script.
How do I avoid the cyan to be included in the exported image without clearing the selection?

Comment: Could you select, zoom to selection, clear selection (remaining at that zoom level/position), and then export?

Comment: No, because it is an iteration for report production. I guess one could could code that situation, but it would be complicated to code, at least for me.